# change the file type .xlsx to .xls in react-export-excel third part library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an excel file using react-export-excel third-party library. But I need to create .xls file, not .xlsx file. So how to Configure them?

```
<ExcelFile element={<MDBIcon icon="file-excel" size="2x" className="green-text" />}>
        <ExcelSheet data={props.email} name="Employees">
            <ExcelColumn label="Email" value="Email" />
            <ExcelColumn label="Quota" value="Quota" />
        </ExcelSheet>
    </ExcelFile>
```

Comment: `<ExcelFile fileExtension="xls"/>` just add this

Comment: it changed .xlsx to .xls file but it doesn't work. The File format is not valid that error occurred

Comment: This is not working, File format is not supported

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-export-excel) you can set the `fileExtension` prop to: `"xls"`.

In your case you can do the following:

```
<ExcelFile
  element={<MDBIcon icon="file-excel" size="2x" className="green-text" />}
  fileExtension="xls"
>
  <ExcelSheet data={props.email} name="Employees">
    <ExcelColumn label="Email" value="Email" />
    <ExcelColumn label="Quota" value="Quota" />
  </ExcelSheet>
</ExcelFile>
```

This prop defaults to `"xlsx"`. So that explains why you're getting your output with that extension.

**Update:**

The problem with this package is that it's a fork of [react-data-export](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/issues). So there aren't any issues on the fork and the `react-data-export` seems like it's not really being maintained.

So it might be worth considering using a different library to accomplish your goal.

It's also worth noting that the difference between `XLS` and `XLSX` might be the reason this would be difficult to accomplish.

A quick Google Search gives this:

> There are differences in the `XLSX` and `XLS` formats created by Excel. While `XLS` files use a proprietary binary format, `XLSX` files use a newer file format referred to as `Open XML`.

This means that the `XLS` binary format actually belongs to Microsoft. This could mean that getting a legit solution to get `XLS` format over `XLSX` wouldn't be a free one.

I've done some research and can't find a single solution for React that will let you generate an `XLS` formatted Excel file. All of them generate in the format `XLSX`.

Comment: it changed .xlsx to .xls file but it doesn't work. The File format is not valid that error occurred

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more research on the topic. Is there a really specific reason you need `xls` over `xlsx`?

Comment: I want .xls file

Comment: When I open the .xls file, an error occurred such as File format is not valid. What is the issue?? But the library's default file format is .xlsx. it works for me. Although I want to create an .xls file only.

Comment: You didn’t answer my question, why do you specifically need xls instead of xlsx?